# jQuery event happen second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am binding an event as follow : when the user left click over the menu, it load a view in a dragbox, the drag box is draggable.

But, It doesn't work as well.. I tried to click twice, first time, the drag box shows up, but is not draggable, and the second time a new box appear again and works as I except..

I don't really get why..

```
var box = [];
var $container = $("#container");

/** DragBox Init */

function DragBox(url, controller) {
this.url = url;
this.htmlcontent = "";
this.controller = controller;
this.test = "null";

this.requestContent = function() { 
    $.get(this.url, null, function(res) {
        $container.append(res);
    });
}

this.requestContent();
$(this).attr("id", this.controller);
$("#" + this.controller).hide().fadeIn(1000).draggable();
}
```

/** link grabber */

```
var links = $("li a");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
links[i].onclick = function() {
    box.push(new DragBox($(this).attr("href"), $(this).attr("controller")));
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you binding click events like that!?

Comment: Indeed: `$("li a").click(function(){...});` will do the same job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the box you want to drag supposed to be appended to the DOM during the requestContent call?

If so, I assume the problem is that you're trying to drag the box prior to have it loaded, which is why it works only the second time (since at least the first one has been loaded).

Anyway, the issue is that `requestContent` is asynchronous since it calls the server, so you should wait until it's done before doing the rest, which is possible by executing your code when that function tells you you can do so, by invoking what is called a callback:

```
function DragBox(url) {
  // init stuff...

  this.requestContent = function(callback) { 
    $.get(url, function(res) {
      var $element = $(res);
      $element.appendTo($container);
      $element.hide();
      // The job is done, execute the code inside callback
      callback($element);
    });
  }

  // Render the requested html content and make it draggable
  this.requestContent(function($element) {
    $element.fadeIn(1000).draggable();
  });

}
```

Comment: I also tried to directly inset id in my views instead of adding with attr, doesn't work.. still loading after the second time

Comment: Ok I've edited my code to make it cleaner: you don't need to set and read ids at all, instead you can just give the box to your callback so after its loading it can be made draggable. Actually you don't even need to declare requestContent and then call it just after, you could just write all the code at once.

Answer (score 1):

try using

`$('li a').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
DragBox($(this).attr("href"), $(this).attr("controller"));
})`

this will bind the click event, you don't need to use a for loop

try to use jquery-ui to make them draggable
[Jquery-ui draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: Your syntax is invalid... you need to wrap the call to DragBox in an anonymous function in order to pass parameters. This will just call DragBox  immediately and pass the result to click.

Comment: +1 for thinking to add `e.preventDefault()` to an anchor click :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
    if ( /* some condition */ ) {
        var some_var = new DragBox(params);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using the `null` parameter in your `get`? `$.get(this.url, null, function(res) {
        $container.append(res);
    });`

Comment: B/c i don't need to give that request parameters

Comment: Oh ok. You don't need to use `null`, you can just use `$.get(this.url, function(result) ... `